Use JetBrains CleanupCode to format csproj, props, and target files
Is there a way to have the JetBrains tool CleanupCode to use xml formatting with csproj, props, and targets files? So far it seems to ignore my editorconfig settings. I have added this to my editorconfig but does not help:
[*.{csproj,sfproj,dbproj,webproj,deployproj,props,targets}]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4
resharper_substitution_for_cleanup_profile=* => Built-in: Reformat Code

